# How to remove lawyer bookcase glass door?

Tags: shelving

The lawyer bookcase has glass doors that slide up over the books. I am attempting to remove the door to replace the glass on one of the shelves.

Top shelf with the door in the retracted position:
[image: Top shelf with the door in the retracted position.]

Detail of the door with wooden pin into the groove on the side wall.
[image: Detail of the door with wooden pin into the groove in the side wall.]

Detail of the groove in the side wall from inside.
[image: Detail of the groove in the side wall from inside.]

How is the door removed?

Comment: I was initially happy reading the first four words of your title: How to remove lawyer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unscrew the rollers on both sides.

Lower the door so it's parallel to the back.

Push one end back into the cabinet until the pin is free of the side slot - or start with the door at the back, and pull one end forward until it's free of the side slot (and then keep pulling forward to remove from the case.)

Replacement should be the reverse of removal.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. My bookcase didn't have rollers, but I removed a dowel like pin on top of  each side, and instead of removing the little magnets on the bottom sides, I just lifted ithe door up so that it was behind the magnet and then I was able to push it sideways so that it would come out.
But this article helped.